# ¿Como atrapo un session-timeout con java?

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

Hace solo 3 meses que estoy investigando de a poco en el trabajo sobre Java.

Mi problema es que implementé un session-timeout (de 1 minuto para probar) en una aplicación Java/mvc montada sobre un servidor Oracle WebLogic g11, la cuestion es que cuando llega al timeout seteado en el web.xml el servidor "muere", o no hace nada hasta que actualizo la URL del navegador (de esto me di cuenta debuggeando, no detalla nada la consola, ni el debugguer corre por el .java validador de session que se ejecuta con cada interaccion al sistema). Las llamadas a los botones o interacciones del sistema se hacen la mayoria por Ajax.

mi web.xml:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>AjaxSessionExpirationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>AjaxSessionExpirationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>customSessionExpiredErrorCode</param-name>
            <param-value>901</param-value>
        </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AjaxSessionExpirationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <session-config> 
   <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

Clase Java:

```
public class AjaxSessionExpirationFilter implements Filter{

private int customSessionExpiredErrorCode = 901;

    @Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException
{
    // Property check here
}

    @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filerChain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpSession currentSession = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession(false);
    if(currentSession == null)
    {
        String ajaxHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("X-Requested-With");
        if("XMLHttpRequest".equals(ajaxHeader))
        {
            logger.info("Ajax call detected, send {} error code: "+ this.customSessionExpiredErrorCode);
            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            resp.sendError(this.customSessionExpiredErrorCode);
        }
        else
        {
            // Redirect to login page
        }
    }
    else
    {
        filerChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub}
```

}

Alguien me da una mano? Gracias!

Comment: Usa un listener, [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) para ser exacto.

Answer (score 0):

Al intentar ayudarte encontré el siguiente ejemplo muy similar al tuyo [ver aqui](http://126kr.com/article/w4kc4e2wi)

y el código https://github.com/doanduyhai/AjaxSessionExpiration